# Change fields from edit mode to readonly

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm using Odoo 15 and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically make a field in the view from 'edit' mode to 'readonly' using JavaScript.

```js
_render: function () {
    return this._renderReadonly();
},
```

Let's say this is an example code. I included this code inside FieldChar basic field (`web.basic_fields.FieldChar`). Unfortunately, this breaks my views if the field is not originally readonly.

[image: Broken fields]

These two fields are originally in 'edit' mode and I want to make them readonly using JavaScript. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Uhmm, why do you want to do that? In which cases do you want to see them as editable fields? You can add a condition in the form view.

Comment: I'm creating encrypted fields. If some field has a custom parameter then this field should be set to readonly and its value changed in view. It's unreal to do this manually by editing every view and attributes so I'm trying to achieve this with JS.

Comment: In the end you have to define those fields in the views anyways, so there won't be much more effort to use the available functionalities of Odoo.

Comment: I think you should manually edit DOM via javascript setting readonly attribute to the input field and adding correct CSS classes/styles if condition is met. You should anyway consider to achieve this via odoo functionalities instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

if you use standart odoo CharField, try to do it in views, not by js. If your condition depends on other field, you can use this example:

```
<field name="your_char_field" attrs="{'readonly': [('state','=', 'manual')]}"/>
```